# Implement Google Contact App Layout into XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm really unsure how to implement the red marked part of Googles Contacts App into XML:

[image: img1]

How to implement this officially correct? LinearLayout can't be that much efficient..

```
<ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>

            <ImageView />

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>

            <ImageView />

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Result:**
[image: img2]